# mod_rewrite `.htaccess` rules with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My permalinks on Wordpress for posts/pages are:

> `www.foo.com/%postname%`

I want to be able to redirect the following:

> **from:** `www.foo.com/web-design/%location%`
>   **or:**   `www.foo.com/web-development/%location%`
>
> **to:**   `www.foo.com/index.php?location=%location%`

*NB: I don't have any posts/pages with the name `web-design` or `web-development` to avoid clashes.*

---

My `.htaccess` in root has the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^web-design/([^/]*)$ /index.php?location=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^web-development/([^/]*)$ /index.php?location=$1 [L]

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

---

- If I visit `/index.php?location=foo`, the page shows as expected.
- If I visit `/web-design/foo` (the rewritten rule), I see a 404 page - **however the correct `$_GET` variables are passed to that page.**

How can I get Wordpress to process this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by renaming the 404 page from `404.php` to `_404.php`.

As a result, Wordpress redirects back to the homepage... but with all the `$_GET` variables intact.

Not the best solution but it's working!